# getting high resolution photos that were posted on a page wall/feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed, image

I'm getting my page wall with the open graph.
And when someone posted a photo, I get it on the JSON

```
{
     "id": "27888702146_10150369820322147",
     "from": {
        "name": "brocoli",
        "category": "Record label",
        "id": "27888702146"
     },
     "message": "Vincent Epplay / David Fenech / Jac Berrocal \u00e0 Beaubourg ce soir, 19h, gratos.",
     "picture": "http://photos-f.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/305819_10150369820292147_27888702146_8255527_583491475_s.jpg",
     "link": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10150369820292147&set=a.386279807146.165840.27888702146&type=1",
     "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif",
     "type": "photo",
     "object_id": "10150369820292147",
     "created_time": "2011-10-16T08:22:21+0000",
     "updated_time": "2011-10-16T08:22:21+0000",
     "likes": {
        "data": [
           {
              "name": "brocoli",
              "category": "Record label",
              "id": "27888702146"
           },
           {
              "name": "Agathe Morier",
              "id": "601668526"
           }
        ],
        "count": 2
     },
     "comments": {
        "count": 0
     },
     "is_published": true
  }
```

The problem is that the picture link is a low resolution copy of the picture.

How can I get the URL of the full picture ?

Thanks!!

Best

Geoffroy

Comment: Have you got the solution , the below answer not working.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can get different version of the `photo` by querying Graph API with its `object_id` (not photo `post_id` which is `id` in results you provided).

Once you'll request the `photo` by object `id` you'll get array of `images` with URLs and dimensions:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/10150369820292147?fields=images
```

If you're attempting to access posts on a *Facebook Page* (such as for a company) instead of typical user profile, you firstly need to fetch the feed like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/YOUR_PAGE_ID_HERE/feed?fields=attachments&access_token=...
```

And then access `data[0].attachments.data[0].subattachments.data[0].target.id` to get the object ID (or "target ID" in this case) which you can then use to perform an additional query to obtain the higher resolution image. Increment the numbers to get additional posts and images inside each post.

Comment: @Juicy Scripter What if i don't have an object_id in my feed.

Comment: @Juicy Scripter, Thanks for the great answer but for the feed type "Video" it is failing with below response. {"error":{"message":"Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/docs\/graph-api","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100}}

Comment: @Juicy Scripter : not working ' Unsupported get request '  http://graph.facebook.com/397556853726341?fields=images

Comment: @VineeshTP working for me, perhaps you're not using the correct object_id field?

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do is :

```
http://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=picture.height(961) 
// replace 961 with your required height which u want
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Only thing working right now.

Comment: This only gets your profile pic, not all the photos in your feed.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this from the main posts list now using

```
/v2.3/105753476132681/posts?limit=5&fields=likes.summary(true),comments.summary(true), attachments
```

If attachments doesn't work, try full_picture - but that just gave the 100x100 image for me as well.

Attachments returns a data hash with a 640x480 version of the image at least (not sure what my orig. photo size was)

Comment: This might work for a typical user feed, but not for a Facebook *Page*, which currently limits images to 720px. You instead need to use the [method mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9821883/195835) by Juicy Scripter.

Answer (score 2):

Use this Code. Its Work for me and get Clear Image

```
String PICTURE_URL;

String getPicture = hashMap.get("picture");
        if (getPicture.contains("_t.")) {
            PICTURE_URL = getPicture.replaceAll("_t.", "_n.");
        } else if (getPicture.contains("_a.")) {
            PICTURE_URL = getPicture.replaceAll("_a.", "_n.");
        } else if (getPicture.contains("_s.")) {
            PICTURE_URL = getPicture.replaceAll("_s.", "_n.");
        } else if (getPicture.contains("_q.")) {              
            PICTURE_URL = getPicture.replaceAll("_q.", "_n.");
        }
        url=new URL(PICTURE_URL);
        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_FullImage)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: By me it works sometimes and sometimes not.... why did facebook made getting an image so stupid

Answer (score 2):

Though requesting a photo by its `object_id` will return an array of images with different dimensions, in some cases this approach would require an additional call to the Facebook API.

A simpler approach is to add `full_picture` to your list of parameters, which will extract the highest resolution image associated with the post.

```
/v2.2/6275848869/posts?fields=full_picture
```

For example, if you want to extract all the posts from a Facebook page in the past X days, with the `object_id` approach you'd need to call the API 3 times:

1. To get the page info.
2. To extract the list of posts and obtain the `object_id` for each post.
3. For each `object_id`, to retrieve the list of higher resolution images.

Comment: Unfortunately this has two problems: it doesn't fetch the highest resolution when used on Facebook posts assigned to a "Page", and it only fetches a single image. Some posts can have multiple images attached.