# Facebook NSArray Issue

Tags: ios, ipad, facebook-graph-api, nsarray, facebook-wall

Right now am making a Facebook application for iPad. I am currently loading the wall of the user into a tableview. The problem is when it encounters an image, Facebook is retuning a low-resolution of the image. So to fix this issue, I found this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821586/getting-high-resolution-photos-that-were-posted-on-a-page-wall-feed), But How would I do that in the iOS SDK? because when I get a Facebook result and then determine the object ID, and then re-query Facebook, how would I get them into the NSArray like referred to in the above answer. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the call and observed the resulting json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, it is delivered to you as an NSArray!  You just need to know how to access it from the result object:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    // here's the array
    NSArray *images = [result objectForKey:@"images"];
    //then here's some bonus code for looping through them
    for (NSDictionary *image in images) {
        NSLog(@"source url=%@", [image objectForKey:@"source"]);
        //height and width parameters are also available 
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, but in the tableview it shows the same image twice. I tracked this down and this is because in cellForRowAtIndexPath I am setting an NSDictionary equal to the result so by the time the graph API calls the request did load method a second time for a second image, The tableview is already loaded. How do I fix This??

Comment: post it as another question so we can answer it there

Comment: I posted it as another question. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806272/uitableview-photos-show-up-multiple-times-from-graph-api)