# Asynchrone query in query Facebook Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to display facebookposts of a specific page on my website.

```
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'xxx',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.3'
        });
        var access_token;
        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                $('#AccessToken').val(response.authResponse.accessToken);
                access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                FB.api('/yyy/posts?metadata=1&access_token=' + access_token, function(response) {           
            var text = "";
            var count = 0;

            response.data.forEach(function(element, index, array)
            {
                if(count<3)
                {
                    text = text + "<div id=\"fbpost\">";
                    if(typeof element.picture != "undefined")
                    {
                        text = text+ "<center><img src=\"" + element.picture + "\"></img></center><br>";
                    }
                    text = text+ element.message + "<br>"
                    text = text + element.created_time + "<br>";
                    text = text + "</div>";
                    console.log(element);
                }
                count++;
            });
            text = text + "<div id=fbpostClose></div>"
            console.log(text);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
        });

            } else {
                // do something...maybe show a login prompt
            }
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";/*sdk.js*/
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));          

    </script>
```

This is working like a charm. Except for one thing, the picture you get is only one picture and with a very small resolution.

I found on on [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821586/getting-high-resolution-photos-that-were-posted-on-a-page-wall-feed) stackoverflow-question, you can query the pictures that belong by the post by object_id:

```
   FB.api('/' + element.object_id + '?fields=images', function(responseimage) 
   {    
        console.log(responseimage);
        responseimage.images.forEach(function(image, index2, array2)
        {
            console.log(image.source);
            text = text + image.source;
            text = text + "<center><img src=\"" + image.source + "\"></img></center><br>";
        });                             
    });
```

I wanted to add this in the code, but it doesn't display the images. I think because of the asynchronous call, so this function does not block the underlying method so it displays the variable text before it's the images are added.

I tried the following code:

```
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'xxx',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.3'
        });
        var access_token;
        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                $('#AccessToken').val(response.authResponse.accessToken);
                access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                FB.api('/yyy/posts?metadata=1&access_token=' + access_token, function(response) {           
            var text = "";
            var count = 0;

            response.data.forEach(function(element, index, array)
            {
                if(count<3)
                {
                    text = text + "<div id=\"fbpost\">";
                    if(typeof element.picture != "undefined")
                    {
                        text = text+ "<center><img src=\"" + element.picture + "\"></img></center><br>";
                        FB.api('/' + element.object_id + '?fields=images', function(responseimage) 
                        {
                            console.log(responseimage);
                            responseimage.images.forEach(function(image, index2, array2)
                            {
                                console.log(image.source);
                                text = text + image.source;
                                text = text + "<center><img src=\"" + image.source + "\"></img></center><br>";
                            });                             
                        });
                    }
                    text = text+ element.message + "<br>"
                    text = text + element.created_time + "<br>";
                    text = text + "</div>";
                    console.log(element);
                }
                count++;
            });
            text = text + "<div id=fbpostClose></div>"
            console.log(text);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
        });

            } else {
                // do something...maybe show a login prompt
            }
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";/*sdk.js*/
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));          



    </script>
```

I could not find anything concerning joining from queries with the Facebook Graph Api.

Comment: "it doesn´t work" is not a sufficient error description, please be more detailed and show us the exact code of what you have tried.

Comment: @luschn added some description. The problem is, when i try to get the images, the other code is getting executed while the function is stil busy.

Comment: make sure you know how asynchronous javascript works. not sure where the problem is, to be honest. show us the code of what you have tried. i guess you just try to call the second api function right after the first one, and not in the callback function of the first one.

Comment: @luschn Added the code i thought should work.

Comment: still not sure what "it does not work" means exactly, but for example, you are closing the div tag outside the callback of the second API call. so the div gets closed before you get any results from facebook. check out "javascript promises", they are very good for those kind of things.

Comment: The call for the pictures is not blocking the other code, so when calling the function for the pictures, it's not waiting till a callback, but starts executing the other code already. So var text with the pictures is set after that text is already displayed.  So it will not display.

Comment: yes, that´s what i meant. go check out promises, they are an easy way to solve this.

Comment: btw, "text += something" is more common than "text = text + something"

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at promises. About + or +=, tought it did not work in javascript.